# bookmark structure for multifile latex file

Tags: bookmarks

I am working on a project in Latex .. the bookmark hierarchy in the pdf is not showing. I didnt write every thin in one file .. I used `\input{...file.tex}`. How can I make sure that latex count the other subsections or sections in the other files?

Comment: using `\input` will have no effect on the bookmark structure, please show the code you used.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I get the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.11 \bookmarksetup` from your example. Where have you defined `\bookmarksetup` ? did you intend to load the `bookmark` package?